# use NSURLProtocol and NSURLSession to do do proxy request,when My proxy server required username and password, it returns warning

Tags: ios, webview, proxy, delegates, nsurlprotocol

I use `NSURLProtocol` and `NSURLSession` to do do a `webview` proxy request,

it works when My Proxy server is Anonymous，

but, when My proxy server required username and password, it returns the following warning

`CFMachPortSetInvalidationCallBack()` called on a `CFMachPort` with a Mach port (0x8e03) which does not have any send rights.  This is not going to work.  Callback function: 0x24232ea1

and the webview alert a window to ask me to fill in `username` and `password`,

when I clicked cancel button,it goes to `- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler`

and my method work.

I don't want to alert the window

who can solve my problem

thans

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem :|

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, too. On iOS 7 only. On iOS 8 it works.